# Generate JAX-WS Source NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, wsdl, jax-ws, mule

I'm trying to generate Java service classes from a WSDL definition I have already created. My current problem is that it fails with the following message, no more detail than that:

```
Unable to generate JAX-WS Source.

Reason:
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

*(yay~ for verboseness)*

I am using MuleStudio 1.3.0, which is based on Eclipse 3.6.1. I have tried creating these classes both from Mule's components and from the WSDL directly, but I get the same error.

I mixed up the WSDL on purpose and it correctly started throwing validation errors. This means that it's reading the file and parsing it properly. Not clue about what happens next.

**How may I troubleshoot this?**

Below is my wsdl file for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/ListenerService/" 
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    name="ListenerService"
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/ListenerService/">
    <!-- types -->
    <wsdl:types>
        <!-- Generic TransactionLog entities -->
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/ListenerService/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xsd:simpleType name="LevelEnumeration">
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:normalizedString">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Debug" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Info" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Warning" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Error" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Fatal" />
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>

            <xsd:complexType name="LogEntry">
                <sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="CorrelationToken" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
                    <xsd:element name="SystemId" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Level" type="tns:LevelEnumeration"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Description" type="xs:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="RecordData" type="xs:string" />
                    <xsd:element name="Timestamp" type="xs:dateTime" />
                </sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <!-- Service Specific Types -->
            <xsd:simpleType name="GenericResponseStatusEnumeration">
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:normalizedString">
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Success" />
                    <xsd:enumeration value="Error" />
                </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:complexType name="ListenerServiceGenericResponse">
                <sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Status" type="tns:GenericResponseStatusEnumeration" />
                    <xsd:element name="Detail" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                </sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>

            <xsd:element name="LogEntry" type="tns:LogEntry" />
            <xsd:element name="ServiceResponse" type="tns:ListenerServiceGenericResponse" />
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <!-- service message types -->
    <wsdl:message name="SubmitLogRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="LogEntry" type="tns:LogEntry" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="SubmitLogResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="Response" type="tns:ListenerServiceGenericResponse" />
    </wsdl:message>

    <!-- service messages -->
    <wsdl:portType name="ListenerService">
        <wsdl:operation name="SubmitLog">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:SubmitLogRequest" />

            <!-- TODO: Remove this to make it a one-way operation -->
            <wsdl:output message="tns:SubmitLogResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <!-- service bindings -->
    <wsdl:binding name="ListenerServiceSOAP">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="SubmitLog">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/ListenerService/SubmitLog" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="ListenerService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:ListenerServiceSOAP" name="ListenerServiceSOAP">
            <soap:address location="http://tempuri.org" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: I would try calling the jaxws wsimport command directly on your Wsdl from a commad line. I believe it comes with the JDK now so you shouldn't even have to download it. You may have run into a bug which has been fixed in a later version of wsimport.

Comment: @davidfrancis Thanks, that was actually the solution to my problem. Running it from the command line gave me a lot of information on which the problems with the WSDL where, but I still cannot figure out why wouldn't it give me any feedback on Eclipse. I'll update the question to reflect that. Thanks again!

Comment: @davidfrancis Well, no, I changed my mind. You answered to my original question and changing it would be to totally change the scope of the question, so I won't do that. Plase, feel free to post your feedback as an answer so I can accept it as the correct way to troubleshoot these issues.

Comment: OK will do, glad to have helped - a bit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try calling the jaxws wsimport command directly on your Wsdl from a command line. 
I believe it comes with the JDK now so you shouldn't even have to download it.
You may have run into a bug which has been fixed in a later version of wsimport.

Comment: PS In Eclipse, you have the Console view which has a drop down box to switch to a number of different consoles. Maybe one of these has some JAX-WS information? Or there is the main Eclipse log file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a console view for JAX-WS, but running the wsimport tool from the command line pointed to a number of issues I had in my wsdl file. Thus, I was able to fix them and get the files generated (which I then had to import into my project). Thanks!